# Sort table from image

Tags: cakephp

I have a table with a column 'read'. I'd like to be able to sort from a graphic rather than text, although can't seem to work it out.

Here's what I've tried:

```
        <!-- none of these work...-->

        <th class="read"><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('read',$this->Html->image("read_no.png", array(
                    'width' => "26px",
                    'alt' => "Read",
                    array('escape' => false)))); ?></th>

        <th class="read"><?php echo $this->Html->link(
            $this->Html->image("read_no.png", array("alt" => "Read")),
            $this->Paginator->sort('read'),
            array('escape' => false)
        );?></th>

        <th class="read"><?php echo $this->Html->image("read_no.png", array(
                    'width' => "26px",
                    'alt' => "Read",
                    'url' => $this->Paginator->sort('read'),
                    array('escape' => false)
                )); ?>
        </th>
```

I get errors like:

```
        The action <a href=" is not defined in controller
```

Comment: if u set it to Text , does it work?

Comment: Have you set Pagination in controller ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the escape option to the Paginator/sort Method rather than the HTML/image one:

```
<th class="read">
    <?php 
       $imageTag = $this->Html->image("read_no.png", array(
                                                         'width' => "26px",
                                                         'alt' => "Read",
                                                      )
                                      );
       echo $this->Paginator->sort('read', $imageTag, array('escape' => false)); ?>
 </th>
```